How to Implement Distributed AutoFAISS with PySpark for Large-Scale Vector Indexing?
I’m working on a project that involves creating a vector search index for a massive dataset consisting of 1.3 trillion tokens. I want to use AutoFAISS in a distributed environment to handle the scale of the data. My current setup involves using PySpark to distribute the indexing tasks across multiple nodes.
Context:
•   I’m setting up a distributed environment with multiple nodes using Apache Spark.
•   The goal is to build and optimize FAISS indices in parallel across these nodes to manage the large-scale data efficiently.

Problem:
I’m encountering challenges in correctly configuring and implementing the distributed setup using PySpark and AutoFAISS. Specifically:
•   How should I configure PySpark and the Spark cluster to ensure efficient parallel processing across nodes?
•   What are the best practices for setting up the environment (e.g., memory management, network configuration) to avoid common pitfalls?
•   How do I properly handle data shuffling and node communication to optimize the performance of distributed AutoFAISS?

Current Setup:
•   I’m using Ubuntu 20.04 on all nodes.
•   Apache Spark 3.2.1 is installed on both the master and worker nodes.
•   AutoFAISS is downloaded and ready to be executed via PySpark.
Steps Taken:
•   I’ve set up the Spark cluster and configured the worker nodes.
•   Attempted to run AutoFAISS using a PySpark script, but I’m facing issues with resource allocation and parallel processing efficiency.

Questions:
1.  What specific PySpark configurations (e.g., executor memory, cores) are recommended for running AutoFAISS in a distributed environment?
2.  Are there any examples or best practices for effectively managing such a large-scale vector indexing task using PySpark?
3.  How can I optimize the Spark cluster setup to minimize latency and maximize throughput during the indexing process?

I'm mostly working off of this article: Indexing 1T Vectors (https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki/Indexing-1T-vectors). I think the data is too big for AutoFaiss, but I can use that for experiments.
